# set list-style-type: none only on image when using ul li

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS

```
ul.xoxo.blogroll {      
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left: 27px;  
}
ul.xoxo.blogroll li img { 
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

now i use `list-style-type: none;` and cicrcle is not visible. But i would like that circle will be visible when i am using `ul li` and not visible when `ul li` has `img` tag.

Is that possible. If i set

```
ul.xoxo.blogroll {
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left: 27px;  
}

ul.xoxo.blogroll li img { 
        list-style-type: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

circles are everywhere.

Comment: So you want a list style type to be `none` if there is an `<img>` inside the list item, otherwise have it to default? There is no way of affecting a parent after seeing if the child exists I'm afraid (as this involves going "up" the dom, CSS can only go down(cascade)), can be done with jQuery though

Comment: yes this is exactly what i want. hmm so only ajax can help me? do you know for any goof tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got you right, if there is a `<img>` inner a `<ul>`, you want the `list-type-style` to be `none`, and otherwise a `circle`?

if so, i think you need to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

**jQuery:**

```
​​$('ul.xoxo.blogroll img').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('listStyleType','none');
    });​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The script loops trough every `<img>` tag, and with `.parent().css()` it manipulates the css attributes of its parent, what the `<li>` would be.

Did it work?

**Edit**: Here's a jsFiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Wc72f/

Comment: Be careful, if you change your hirarchy where `<li>` isn't the nearest parent of your `<img>` any longer, then you have to use `.parent('li')` instead `.parent()`. More about: [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) @senzacionale

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no CSS selector for a parent of a specific child. If you want to stay with CSS only, you can add another class, e.g. `imglist` or similar, and select on that.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ul.xoxo.blogroll li.img { 
    list-style-type: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

it works if I understand the question correctly

Comment: Your code here is looking for an LI tag with a class of 'img'. Not relevant I'm afraid.